# Compare array values with same key in PHP

Tags: php, arrays, compare

I am trying to compare the values of 2 arrays with the same key and see if the value of the array with the same key is greater than the other. Here's the arrays:

```
Array
(
    [3203] => 2
    [7276] => 1
)
Array
(
    [3203] => 1
    [7276] => 1
)
```

The part of the code that produced the array above:

```
foreach ($this->request->post['quantity'] as $key => $value)
{           
    $cart_value[$key] = $value;
}

foreach ($this->session->data['cart'] as $id => $val) {

$stock[$id] = $this->cart->availableStock($id);
}
```

How can I compare the value of each key?

I have this if else statement:

```
if ($cart_value > $stock) {
  // do something<br>
} elseif ($cart_value = $stock) {
  // do another thing
} else {
  // do this thing
}
```

Thank you for your help.

Comment: What should happen if one of the values having the same key is bigger than the other?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can nest foreach loops.

```
foreach ($array1 as $k1 => $v1) {
    foreach {$array2 as $k2 => $v2) {
        if ($k1 === $k2) {
            switch (true) {

               case ($v1 < $v2):
                   // less than
                   break;
               case ($v1 > $v2):
                   // more than
                   break;
               case ($v1 == $v2):
                   // equal
                   break;
               default:
                   // values cannot be compared
                   break;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Use [array_intersect_assoc](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-intersect-assoc.php) on the arrays and then use [count](http://php.net/manual/en/function.count.php) to see if the result is the same size.

Alternatively, use [array_diff_assoc](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-diff-assoc.php) and see if the result is empty.

All depends what you want to do with the result. The first option will return an array containing elements that match, and the second option will return an array containing elements that do not match.

If you want the results to be based on a specific formula (e.g. return only items where the value is greater in the second array), you can use [array_uintersect_assoc](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-uintersect-assoc.php)